# ui automation test in android using uiautomator

Tags: android

I am very new to testing.I am trying to automate my test to test an app. It has email and password field and login. I am filling the email and then the password and after that I am clicking on Log In button.

```
new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").resourceId("com.yml.usemefinal:id/email2")).setText("admin");         
new UiObject(new UiSelector().className("android.widget.EditText").resourceId("com.yml.usemefinal:id/password")).setText("rajesh");
UiObject login=new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Log In"));    
login.click();
```

but it first fills the email field and then it fills the password in the email only. Where is the error.?

Answer (score 1):

This should work I guess.
Can you try accessing element through text or description once if that is available for Email and password field.
I have already used it in my code once as :

```
        new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Email"))
                .setText("yrewi@abc.com");

        UiObject psswrd = new UiObject(
                new UiSelector().description("password"));
        psswrd.setText("abc123");

        new UiObject(new UiSelector().text("Create an Account"))
                .clickAndWaitForNewWindow();
```

Ans this works for me.